# Java regular expression bug

Tags: java, regex

I have the following regular expression:

```
^(MIN|MAX|SUM|AVERAGE):[(\\d+(\\.\\d+)?), ]+$
```

The rule I am attempting to implement should allow only for strings of the following format:

```
OPERATION: (comma separated list of integers or real numbers)
```

For example the following must be allowed:

```
MIN: 7, 89.7, 67
AVERAGE: 67.9, 89, 9
```

However, it accepts input of the form

```
MAX: ,
```

How can I avoid having blank spaces on either side of the comma to be accepted?

Comment: what about negative numbers, or scientific notation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
"^(MIN|MAX|SUM|AVERAGE)\\s?:\\s?(\\d+(\\.\\d+)?)(,\\s?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?)*$"
```

Tests:

```
MIN:4: true
MIN:4,4: true
MIN:4, 5: true
MIN:4 , 5: false
MIN: 7, 89.7, 67: true
AVERAGE: 67.9, 89, 9: true
MAX: , : false
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex

```
^(MIN|MAX|SUM|AVERAGE):\s*\d+(\.\d+)?(\s*,\s*\d+(\.\d+)?)*$
```

Answer (score 1):

Character classes can not contain regex constructs, as you have attempted.

This is a slightly different spin on the other answers that results in a smaller regex:

```
(MIN|MAX|SUM|AVERAGE): \\d+(\\.\\d+)?(, \\d+(\\.\\d+)?)*
```

The don't need the leading and trailing `^` and `$` - they are implied.

To use:

```
if (str.matches("(MIN|MAX|SUM|AVERAGE): \\d+(\\.\\d+)?(, \\d+(\\.\\d+)?)*") {
    // yes, format is OK
}
```

Comment: the use of `^`,`$` depends on the method he's using to match!

Comment: @Anirudh There is only `String.match()` which must match the entire input, which is why the start/end is redundant

Comment: @Bohemian What about Matcher.find()?

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan what about it? He's not parsing, he's *validating* input: *should allow only for strings of the following format*. String.matches() is the only sane choice.

Answer (score 0):

this will accept any of your "operations", the ":" symbol and any numer/dot, comma-separated, with or without spaces before the 1st number or after any comma. 
It will also prevent your line to end with a comma.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^(MIN|MAX|SUM|AVERAGE):\\s?(\\d+?(\\.\\d+?)?,?\\s?)+?\\d$");
```

Answer (score -1):

You have a blank space in you pattern, so you'd have to tweak it a little, the quickest alteration would be this, so that you can still have blank spaces in between your list elements:

```
"^(MIN|MAX|SUM|AVERAGE):[(\d+(\.\d+)?)][(\d+(\.\d+)?), ]+$"
```